# How to get google sheets from this url that has "/e" in it (ultimate goal is to get the json)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the json from a googlesheet

the sheet is published at:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ7VXz3uE1SkR_7JyU5FdzLkdIvM_hUjUfHBSSS5xshCL0ZmmE_JVxc3rqI5p1sNGUZWS7SMVrlIcyf/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

None of the examples I've seen for getting the google sheet key have a url with the "/e" in it.

The examples I've seen are of the form

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/GOOGLE-SHEET-KEY/default/public/full?alt=json

I'm thinking the key should be "2PACX-1vQ7VXz3uE1SkR_7JyU5FdzLkdIvM_hUjUfHBSSS5xshCL0ZmmE_JVxc3rqI5p1sNGUZWS7SMVrlIcyf", but that doesn't work.

And I've tried using the stuff with and without the "/e", but none of them work for getting the json for the sheet.

Maybe something silly going on, so any help appreciated.

Comment: How about these patterns? 1. If you want to use the ID of ``2PACX-...``, for example, how about converting the JSON object after the data is retrieved as CSV file, because the data cannot be directly retrieved as JSON object? 2. If you can use the file ID instead of ``2PACX-...``, you can directly retrieve the JSON object.

Comment: This is an "export link" rather than a link to the editable/shareable Drive item. You'll need the actual item link to extract its ID

Comment: Consider also using the url parameter `output` to change output. For example, `.../pub?output=csv` will result in a CSV-formatted output. Probably TSV or CSV will be most useful, but XLSX, ODS, and PDF are also available for webpage-published documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Google Sheet data as JSON you use the url:

`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/GOOGLE-SHEET-KEY/od6/public/values?alt=json`

You can only get the **Google Sheet Key** if you have access to the document (i.e. If you are the creator or if you have a shareable link)

When you publish the document to the web, you get a 'published to web' URL similar to this:

[image]

But having this URL doesn't give you the **Google Sheet Key**

- If you are the creator of the spreadsheet, you simply have to go to the page where you edit your document.

[image]

In the URL of the page, the **Google Sheet Key** is present between:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/` and `/edit#gid=0`

(#gid=< any number > ...varies with different sheets)

- If you are not the creator of the spreadsheet you need to get the 'shareable link' URL obtained by clicking the 'Share button' and clicking 'Get shareable link'... That will give you the shareable link

[image]

In the link **Google Sheet Key** is present between:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/` and `/edit?usp=sharing`

> Note: Incase you get an error *"We're sorry. This document is not published."* on loading the JSON page, it means the document hasn't been published to the web.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the same URL that returns HTML table

[image: HTML table]

And then use something like [html-table-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-table-to-json) to get a JSON

You can use RegEx to crop if multiple tables found on the HTML